# Show that the phi function is multiplicative $\phi(mn) = \phi(m)\phi(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, multiplicative-function

Show that the phi function is multiplicative $$\phi(mn) = \phi(m)\phi(n)$$

---

Any nice way to prove this without using induction ? The textbook proof looks bit awkward to me, so I am trying to see if it makes sense using other methods. Appreciate any help :D